# Not able to get visible text from some paragraph by using javascript executor and web driver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

In a site I have:

```
<p id="tempid" value="Manual Effect">testing the test</p>
```

```
String value = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) this).executeScript("return window.document.getElementById('tempid').value");
System.out.println("value is : " + value);
```

I am getting null value or nothing.
I want to get the test "testing the test" as output.

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript in the first place?

Comment: typecasting webdriver

Comment: Well **why**? You are getting the text from an element. You can do that without JavaScript.

Comment: If you are using Java script, you don't need WebDriver. On a side note, `value` attribute is not `text`

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone already mentioned. Don't use Javascript. If you do, you don't need WebDriver.

```
WebElement para = driver.findElement(By.id("tempid"));
String text = para.getText(); //this will return "testing the test"
String value = para.getAttribute("value"); //this will return "Manual Effect"
```

Answer (score 0):

> [image: testing the test]

Sir,
You try this solution...

String script = "return document.getElementByTagName('p').tempid.getInnerHtml()";

String script1 = "return document.getElementById('tempid').innerHTML;

JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;

String value = (String)js.executeScript(script);

System.out.println(value);

JavascriptExecutor is more better than webdriver ant many assepect.
WebDriver are work on the basis of webElements, some time if webElement is not accessible. It Show staleElementException, ElementNotFoundException..., Its some time headache.

But JavaScript Executor work directly On HTML. So that why its better...

Answer (score -1):

```
(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this)
                    .executeScript("return window.document.getElementById('tempid').innerHTML");
```

Comment: Simple use webdriver.findElement(By.Id('tempid')) . Why are you using Javascript? It is also visible. Its not a good practice.

Comment: Actually i tried with that also but i am not creating an object just inheriting the firefox driver so i used super word but it throwing error super is a reserved identifier

Comment: Show us the code what you are doing and the stack trace.